# Phusion Passenger: what causes "Cleaning stale instance...Directory not empty" message when using passenger-config or passenger-status

Tags: passenger

It seems everytime I restart my Rails 6.0 application using `passenger-config restart-app /path/to/app`, I get a warning that there are stale instances, like so:

```
*** Cleaning stale instance directory /home/user/rails_apps/passenger-instreg/passenger.gJHicfi
    Warning: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /home/user/rails_apps/passenger-instreg/passenger.gJHicfi
```

I did configure a specific `PassengerInstanceRegistryDir` in the Apache module configuration, as well as defined the `PASSENGER_INSTANCE_REGISTRY_DIR` env variable, but still, my `user` (under which I run the passenger utilities) does not seem have the correct permissions to remove the stale directories.

How do I avoid this?

I run Passenger 6.0.6 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa), with Ruby 2.7.1 installed via rbenv.

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this?